# How to save and load selected Dropdown values in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, binaryformatter

I am trying to make a dropdown that allows you to select different ways to display time. I got it all working except I need to find a way to save and load the option the player selected.

```
private void Start() {
    timeDropdown.options.Clear();
    List < string > items = new() {
        "",
        DateTime.Now.ToString(),
        DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString(),
        DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()
    };

    foreach(var item in items) {
        timeDropdown.options.Add(new TMP_Dropdown.OptionData() {
            text = item
        });
    }

    DropdownItemSelected(timeDropdown);

    timeDropdown.onValueChanged.AddListener(delegate {
        DropdownItemSelected(timeDropdown);
    });
}

void DropdownItemSelected(TMP_Dropdown timeDropdown) {
    int index = timeDropdown.value;

    timeText.text = timeDropdown.options[index].text;
}
```

I think you would use an int to save it but I don't know how to do that. Thank you.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

You could use unity's player prefs system below is a link to documentation on how it works.
[Unity player prefs documentaion](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.SetInt.html)

Alternatively you could create your serialisation system here's a Brackey's video which shows how to make a basic class serialisations system
[YouTube tutorial](https://youtu.be/XOjd_qU2Ido)

For what your trying to do the fastest and quickest approach would be to just use player prefs for saving and loading the int value.

Comment: I have the save system and everything I have it all down I just don’t know how to save and load the int to represent what option in the drop down the player picked